# Sharepoint 2007 Wiki Pages Programming - Input Validation

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wiki

I am using sharepoint event handler Item Adding for Wiki Site.

I need to capture input text and validate against some criteria.

I am unable to get the same.I have already used  properties.BeforeProperties

properties.AfterProperties and DictionaryEntry object.

But nothing works as it is supposed to be.

Suggest other approach.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get inputs value in properties.BeforeProperties,
properties.AfterProperties and DictionaryEntry object when I was trying to use ItemAdding event.

I actually wanted to get inputs value in Itemadding,validate input and show error message.But got no solution.

So, I used ItemAdded event handler,but cant show any error message.

I also tried to delete page if its showing some other error written below ....

...page is modified by...at...some time

So finally I ended up to use Approval status.I have validated inputs from ItemAdded eventand rejected if its not validated and pending if its validated,so that it will be available for approver to approve.

But,I am stil searching solution for my problem using ItemAdding .